# Exclusion of a protected sub-url does not work on Apache 2.4?

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4, http-basic-authentication

I try to exclude a sub-url "/shop/api" from my protected website. It worked fine on different server on Apache/2.2.15 but now not with Apache/2.4.7? It always asks for the basic authentication. Any Idea what I did wrong?

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName 'Authentication required'
AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/pwd/.htpasswd

# Allow access to excluded diretories
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/shop/api/  noauth=1
Order deny,allow
Satisfy any
Deny from all
Require valid-user
Allow from env=noauth
```

Comment: I am not clear on what you want to happen. Is your goal to have all directories protected by basic auth, with the exception of `/shop/api` which should allow anybody in without authentication?

Comment: yes exactly on `/shop/api`  is running a php app which uses their own custom authentication

Comment: The Auth/Access control stuff has been changed considerably in 2.4 you'll need to re-engineer your  configuration.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

as "lain" pointed out the apache 2.4 Auth/Access control stuff [has changed since 2.2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#run-time). So I needed to modify it as follows:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName 'Authentication required'
AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/pwd/.htpasswd
# Allow access to excluded directories
SetEnvIf Request_URI /shop/api  noauth=1
<RequireAny>
  Require env noauth
  Require env REDIRECT_noauth
  Require valid-user
</RequireAny>
```

In addition I had to add `Require env REDIRECT_noauth` because PHP is using some redirect and this keeps the env variable `noauth` set

Comment: Magic! After 3 days of trying to config this, `Require env REDIRECT_noauth` did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: After trying a million solutions on the internet, this one worked. Thank you.