# The behavior of SetEnvIf on PHP routes

Tags: apache-2.4, php5, symfony

We are using the [mod_auth_openid plugin](https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc) to provide OpenID support for part of our site. It works pretty well, but we're running into one of those "Do this, except when" conditions, and I'm not sure where I'm missing.

There are a few URIs that we don't want this applied. On the surface, this is pretty straight forward.

```
<Directory "/opt/homeapp/web">
  AuthType openid-connect
  SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/(callbacks.php.*)$" allow

  require claim hd:example.com
  require env allow
  require valid-user
</Directory>
```

This works fine for things that hit the `callbacks.php` file, and any other actual-file.

Where my problem comes in, is attempting to match Symfony routes. If the incoming request is to `/combobulator/newForm`, it seems like `Request_URI` should be equal to `/combobulator/newForm`. However, this is definitely not the case.

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/combobulator/(.*)" allow
SetEnvIf Request_URI "combobulator/(.*)$" allow
SetEnvIf Request_URI "combobulator" allow
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(combobulator)" allow
```

All of those don't do the thing.

How do you match routes with `SetEnvIf`, or is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing some investigation into how the dataflow works, I've implemented a bit of a test harness to see what `Request_URI` is at this stage of execution.

```
<Directory "/opt/homeapp/web">
  AuthType openid-connect
  SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/(callbacks.php.*)$" allow
  SetEnvIf Request_URI "(.*)" check_uri=$1

  require claim hd:example.com
  require env allow
  require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Then using a custom `LogFormat` statement using `%{check_uri}e` in it, I've managed to show that `Request_URI` at this stage for most routes is `index.php`.

Which is to day, **The SetEnvIf method used for files, will not work for routes**. Some other method will need to be used.

Answer (score -1):

This solved an issue for me with the wp-json api route `Require env REDIRECT_noauth`
[Exclusion of a protected sub-url does not work on Apache 2.4?](https://serverfault.com/questions/725004/exclusion-of-a-protected-sub-url-does-not-work-on-apache-2-4)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/525081)